# After removal of a dependency in composer, the directory persists

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run the `composer.phar` to update changes, everything goes OK. But when I run it again to delete unneeded dependencies, the dependencies are deleted but their directory structure persists such as `mopa/bootstrap-bundle`.

Are there any way to do that properly using Composer?

Comment: This should generally not happen, but perhaps the symlink tricks used by mopa/bootstrap-bundle cause this issue? In any case if it happens with all packages please report it as an issue on github.